# MATLAB LDA error when using k-fold cross validation but not when using holding-out cross validation

Tags: matlab, validation, machine-learning, classification, training-data

I have a 2-D matrix in matlab and i want classify it with LDA.
at first i used holding out cross validation.(i separate my original data in two part.first part consist of 90% randomly chose data of original matrix as training data and second part that consist of the rest of original data as test. )
whit this method it run correctly but after that i decided to use k-fold cross validation instead,so  i divide my original data in to 10 part and for each time i used 9 part as training data and the remain one as test,but when i perform classify in matlab it give me "The pooled covariance matrix of TRAINING must be positive definite." error.

i read past discussion about the reason that matlab give this error but i have not any Nan in my original matrix so i don't have any in sub-matrix,and because observations are not linear combinations of each other in my original matrix and the sub-matrix in holding out method so i conclude that in all sub-matrix in cross validation method it is same.

so i cant find the cause of said error.why matlab give me error when i use cross validation method and not with holding out method?

Comment: How many data points do you have, and how many variables?

Comment: i have 4320 observation vector and each vector consist of 1000 sample,so i have 4320 X 1000 matrix as my training dataset.

Comment: I have deleted my answer, since it apparently does not solve your problem. I have also voted to close your question, because it does not contain enough information to find an answer.